# single page with multiple kendo autocomplete fields

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, autocomplete

Is there a way for me to specify multiple autocomplete elements on a single page with different K-options(datasource)?? Whenever user Picks an item from 1st autocomplete field & navigate to 2nd autocomplete field to pick another item the selected records from 1st autocomplete field disappears.

If k-options attribute is same for 1st and 2nd autocomplete element then records doesn't seem to disappear from 1st autocomplete field? I think it has something to do with the datasources being different in 1st & 2nd autocomplete elements...

```js
$scope.select1Options = {
            placeholder: "Search Par...",
            noDataTemplate: 'No Partner&apos;s found',
            dataTextField: "Name",
            dataValueField: "Id",
            valuePrimitive: false,
            autoBind: false,
            //filter: "contains",
            //animation: {
            //    close: {
            //        effects: "fadeOut zoom:out",
            //        duration: 300
            //    },
            //    open: {
            //        effects: "fadeIn zoom:in",
            //        duration: 300
            //    }
            //},
            minLength: 3,
            dataSource: {
                //type: "odata",
                serverFiltering: true,
                serverPaging: true,
                pageSize: 10,
                filtering: function (e) {
                    var filter = e.filter;

                    if (!filter.value) {
                        //prevent filtering if the filter does not value
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                },
                transport: {

                    read: {
                        url: "/Partner/Configuration/GetPartners",
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'json'
                    }, 
                    parameterMap: function (options, type) {
                        if (type === "read") {
                            var paramMap = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(options);
                            delete paramMap.$inlinecount; // <-- remove inlinecount parameter.
                            delete paramMap.$format; // <-- remove format parameter.
                            return { searchCriteria: options.filter.filters[0].value };
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        data: function (data) {
                            return data; // <-- The result is just the data, it doesn't need to be unpacked.
                        },
                        total: function (data) {
                            return data.length; // <-- The total items count is the data length, there is no .Count to unpack.
                        }
                    }
                }


            },
            select: function(e) {

                $('select[name="multi_select1[]"]').change(function() {
                    $scope.partner = $(this).val();
                });
            }
        };

        $scope.select2Options = {
            placeholder: "Search Emp...",
            noDataTemplate: 'No Employers&apos;s found',
            dataTextField: "Name",
            dataValueField: "EmpId",
            valuePrimitive: false,
            autoBind: false,
            //filter: "contains",
            //animation: {
            //    close: {
            //        effects: "fadeOut zoom:out",
            //        duration: 300
            //    },
            //    open: {
            //        effects: "fadeIn zoom:in",
            //        duration: 300
            //    }
            //},
            minLength: 3,
            dataSource: {
                //type: "odata",
                serverFiltering: true,
                serverPaging: true,
                pageSize: 10,
                filtering: function (e) {
                    var filter = e.filter;

                    if (!filter.value) {
                        //prevent filtering if the filter does not value
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                },
                transport: {

                    read: {
                        url: "/Partner/Configuration/GetEmployers",
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'json'
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (options, type) {
                        if (type === "read") {
                            var paramMap = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(options);
                            delete paramMap.$inlinecount; // <-- remove inlinecount parameter.
                            delete paramMap.$format; // <-- remove format parameter.
                            return { searchText: options.filter.filters[0].value };
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        data: function (data) {
                            return data; // <-- The result is just the data, it doesn't need to be unpacked.
                        },
                        total: function (data) {
                            return data.length; // <-- The total items count is the data length, there is no .Count to unpack.
                        }
                    }
                }


            },
            select: function (e) {

                $('select[name="multi_select2[]"]').change(function () {
                    $scope.employer = $(this).val();
                });
            }
        };
```

```html
<select kendo-multi-select k-options="select1Options" k-ng-model="configuration" k-min-length="3" name="multi_select1[]" class="form-control" ></select>

 <select kendo-multi-select k-options="select2Options" k-ng-model="configuration" k-min-length="3" name="multi_select2[]" class="form-control" ></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, it's because both the kendo autocomplete instances have same k-ng-model attribute. Unfortunately in my case both needs to point to same ng-model but the datatext fields within them are different. How do we solve this problem??